# How to move the object on the touch of a finger using SensorManager?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sensormanager

I have a problem and i can't find a answer for it...

I'm using now a `SensorManager` in my Android game in eclipse. But I want to remove that and replace it with code so the object moves by the touch of the finger on the screen.

Now I'm using this:

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

//sensor
SensorManager sm;
Sensor s;
float sensorx, calibratex = 0;
float sensory, calibratey = 0;
boolean default_lanscape = false;

    //sensors
    sm = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() != 0) {
        s = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
```

Which function must I use to move by touch?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have a look into `View.OnTouchListener` interface